# git submodule already exist but it doesn't?

Tags: linux, git, vim, git-submodules

I have git repo: https://github.com/bbialek/dotfiles
I want to create submodule for vim's pathogen plugin.

```
cd ~/dotfiles/vim
git submodule add https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen .vim
```

It says:

> 'vim/.vim' already exists in the index

Is it because I already have submodules in 
../dotfiles/vim/.vim/bundles/*  ?

My `.gitmodules`:

```
    [submodule "vim/.vim/bundle/nerdtree"]
    path = vim/.vim/bundle/nerdtree
    url = https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree
[submodule "vim/.vim/bundle/vim-autoformat"]
    path = vim/.vim/bundle/vim-autoformat
    url = https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat
[submodule "vim/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized"]
    path = vim/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized
    url = https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized
[submodule "vim/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible"]
    path = vim/.vim/bundle/vim-sensible
    url = https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible
[submodule "vim/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe"]
    path = vim/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
    url = https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe
[submodule "tmux/.tmux/plugins/tpm"]
    path = tmux/.tmux/plugins/tpm
    url = https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm
```

Comment: what `cat .gitmodules` says ? You probably already have `.vim` folder in yout current directory

Comment: Updated the topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot register a submodule within a declared submodule path (like `vim/.vim/bundle/nerdtree`)

Since you have multiple submodules already using `.vim`, you would need to use a different folder for your `.vim` submodule repo.

Comment: Should I make custom path for `bundle` or for pathogen itself (if possible)?

Comment: @bbPi you can register `github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen` under a custom path: as long as it is *not* `vim/.vim`.

Comment: but how to enable pathogen with custom path ?

Comment: @bbPi by creating a symlink (symbolic link) between the right pathogen path and your submodule path.

Comment: It works :D Thank you for all your help. Have a nice day